# how can i create user and passwords (PINs) based on the codes?

Tags: java

I'm not good in java, still learning.
My task is to create bank account as follows.

> Develop a Java Application based on SDLC that allows the Bank teller
> to create a Bank account for Bank customer with an initial starting balance of
> funds. Both the bank teller and the bank customer can deposit the money in the
> customer account. Only the bank customer can withdraw money from his account up
> to 400,000. The account must always have more than 10,000 after any withdrawal.
> The application should have a loop
> where the customer withdraws money from the account until a minimum amount
> (10,000)required in the account is left. When the customer tries to withdraw
> money that will leave the balance of account less than 10,000 the transaction
> must be declined

```
package simpleBankAccount; 

public class MkomaziAccount {
        private int accountNo;
        private String accountName; // user name for the account.
        private double accBalance; // Account balance
        private double setDailyAmount = 400000.00; // Amount to withdraw per day.
        private static double defaultBalance = 10000.00;
        public int day, i = 1;
    
        public MkomaziAccount(int accountNo, String accountName, double accBalance, double setDailyAmount,
                double defaultBalance) {
            if (accBalance < 0) {
                System.out.println("Starting balance cann't be less than 0. \n Balance set to 0.00Tshs");
            } else {
                this.accountNo = accountNo;
                this.accountName = accountName;
                this.accBalance = accBalance;
                this.setDailyAmount = setDailyAmount;
                this.defaultBalance = defaultBalance;
                System.out.println("Account initialized. \nBalance set to Tshs" + this.accBalance);
            }
        }
    
        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNo;
        }
    
        public String getAccountName() {
            return accountName;
        }
    
        public double getAccountBal() {
            return accBalance;
        }
    
    //method to withdraw funds
        public void transferFunds(double amount) {
            if (amount > accBalance) {
                System.out.printf("Unable to withdraw Tshs%.2f. Insuffient balance. \n", amount);
            } else if (amount > this.setDailyAmount) {
                System.out.printf("You cannot withdraw more than Tshs%.2f" + this.setDailyAmount + "per day.\n",
                        setDailyAmount);
            } else if (amount == defaultBalance || accBalance == defaultBalance) {
                System.out.printf("You cannot withdraw that amount of %.2f. \nYour balance is: %.2f", amount, accBalance);
            } else {
                for (i = 1; i <= day; i++) {
                    this.accBalance -= amount;
                    i++;
                    System.out.printf("The amount of Tshs%.2f successfully withdrawn. \nYour new balance is Tshs%.2f\n",
                            amount, this.accBalance);
                }
            }
        }
    
    //Method to deposit money
        public void addFunds(double nextDouble) {
            if (nextDouble < 0) {
                System.out.println("You cannot deposit negative amount");
            } else {
                this.accBalance += nextDouble;
            }
        }
    }

    
import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class MkomaziAccountTest {
     private static Scanner Mkomazi = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean quit = false;
            int choice;
            int accountNo;
            String accountName;
            double accBalance;
            final double defaultBalance = 10000.00;
        
            System.out.printf("%24s\n","Mkomazi Bank Application V1.0");
            System.out.println("============================================");
            System.out.println("Please enter your personal details below.");
            System.out.println("Please enter Account Name");
            accountName = Mkomazi.nextLine();   
            System.out.println("Please enter Account Number");
            accountNo = Mkomazi.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Please enter Account Name");
            accountName = Mkomazi.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Starting Balance");
            accBalance = Mkomazi.nextDouble();
            
            MkomaziAccount account = new MkomaziAccount(accountNo, accountName, accBalance, accBalance, defaultBalance);
            
            while(!quit) {
                printMainMenu();
                choice = Mkomazi.nextInt();
                
                if (choice == 1) {
                    System.out.printf("Account Name: %s\n Account Balance: Tshs %.2f\n", account.getAccountName(), account.getAccountBal());
                    account.getAccountName();
                } else if (choice == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit: ");
                    account.addFunds(Mkomazi.nextDouble());
                } else if (choice == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
                    account.transferFunds(Mkomazi.nextDouble());
                } else if (choice == 4) {
                    quit = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }
            }
            Mkomazi.close();
            
        }
    
        public static void printMainMenu() {
            System.out.printf("%24s\n" + 
            "=======================================\n" + 
            "Please select an option\n" + 
            "1. Check Balance\n" + 
            "2. Deposit Money\n" + 
            "3. Withdraw Money\n" + 
            "4. Exit the program\n" + 
            "========================================\n" +
            "Choice: ","Mkomazi Bank Application V1.0 ");
                
        }
    
    }
```

> But when press option 1 to check balance, does not print Account
> number and Account Name. Can someone help?
> How can i add PINs (check users's PIN) for account Name users.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: This is what displays ========================================
Choice: 1
Account Name: 
 Account Balance: Tshs 10000.00
Mkomazi Bank Application V1.0 
=======================================
Please select an option
1. Check Balance
2. Deposit Money
3. Withdraw Money
4. Exit the program
========================================
Choice:

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and comment this part :

```
            accountName = Mkomazi.nextLine();   --your accname 
            System.out.println("Please enter Account Number");
            accountNo = Mkomazi.nextInt(); 
            
            System.out.println("Please enter Account Name");
          //accountName = Mkomazi.nextLine(); -- your accname2
            
            System.out.println("Starting Balance");
            accBalance = Mkomazi.nextDouble();
            
            MkomaziAccount account = new MkomaziAccount(accountNo, accountName, accBalance, accBalance, defaultBalance); -- it's use your accname2, accname2 = empty
```

if you comment second accountName, your code working